# Dynatree - disable (or hide) the checkboxes from the children nodes when a node is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I am using `dynatree` to select multi-nodes in a hierarchy of directories.

So, I have investigated the behavior of all built-in options for `selectMode`, but, unfortunately, none of them resolves my problem:

- 1: single-selection (not my case)
- 2: multi-selection

  - it does not select the parent node when all children nodes are selected (ok)
  - it does not select all children nodes when the parent node is selected (not ok)
- 3: hierarchical multi-selection

  - it selects the parent node when all children nodes are selected (not ok)
  - it selects all children nodes when the parent node is selected (ok)

The behavior for my case would be correct if:

- it does not select the parent node when all children nodes are selected

  - selecting all children directories is different from selecting the parent of them
- it selects all children nodes when the parent node is selected

  - otherwise, the user might not understand that the children are also selected

Question #1: How to implement this behavior?

Furthermore, the `dtnode.tree.getSelectedNodes()` is returning redundant nodes:

```
/Foo
/Foo/Bar
```

If `/Foo` is selected, it is already implied that `/Foo/Bar` is selected, for me.

Question #2: How to optimize the selected nodes redundancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that I see involves using `selectMode: 2` and toggling the visibility of the children's checkboxes when selecting a node:

```
//enable or disable redundant children nodes recursively
function toggleChildrenNodes(disableChildren, dtnode) {
    if (!dtnode)
        return;

    if (!dtnode.childList)
        return;

    for (var chIdx = 0; chIdx < dtnode.childList.length; chIdx++) {
        dtnode.childList[chIdx].data.hideCheckbox = disableChildren;
        dtnode.childList[chIdx].render(true);
        //when re-enabling a child node that was previously selected, it should disable their children
        toggleChildrenNodes(disableChildren || dtnode.childList[chIdx].isSelected(), dtnode.childList[chIdx]);
    }
}

$('#myTree').dynatree({
    selectMode: 2,
    checkbox: true,
    onSelect: function(isSelected, dtnode) {
        if(!dtnode)
            return;

        toggleChildrenNodes(isSelect, dtnode);

        //gets the optimized selected nodes
        var dryNodes = $.map(dtnode.tree.getSelectedNodes(), function(currentSelectedNode, idx) {
            if (!currentSelectedNode.data.hideCheckbox) { //skip redundant nodes
                return currentSelectedNode.data.key;
            }
            return null;
        });
        console.log(dryNodes);
    }
});
```

Additionally, if the tree nodes expansion is lazy, it is necessary to handle the new children nodes to keep the consistency:

```
onLazyRead: function(dtnode) {
    if(!dtnode)
        return;

    //[...] business logic

    //[...] possible iteration to add N children

    dtnode.addChild({
        //[...] other properties

        //creates childnode with the checkbox hidden if the parent is selected or hidden due to a higher ancestor
        hideCheckbox: dtnode.isSelected() || dtnode.data.hideCheckbox
    });
}
```